# SQL Passthrough Query - Where Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is my current code:

```
SELECT SSOM.sa, SSOM.kps, SSOM.le
FROM SSOM
WHERE SSOM.sa=1419116
```

However i want to make it so whenever you run the query you get a popup box asking you what where criteria you want?

Comment: Adjust your SQL before making the call. The link from TT tells how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SSOM.sa, SSOM.kps, SSOM.le
FROM SSOM
WHERE SSOM.sa=[MyValue]
```

Comment: I get the following error: ODBC--call failed. [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Operator/operand type mismatch. (#301)

Comment: Right Click your query and choose parameters from the menu. Then add your [MyValue] in there and select the correct data type.

Comment: Cheers JMG however when i right click my query i don't get the option to choose parameters?

Comment: The above will NOT WORK since we talking about a pass-though query.